# Cloudflare With AWS ELB using AWS certs

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, cloudflare

I’m trying to configure Cloudflare to sit in front of my AWS application that uses AWS issued certificates with an AWS via an ELB.

Currently I’ve just point a cname in clouflare to my ELB that uses an AWS cert to serve my application securly, but I’m gettign an error “ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH”.

I haven’t uploaded any certs to cloudflare as I can’t export AWS issued certs. I also haven’t generated any certs via cloudflare.

Do certificates on cloudfare need to match certs on AWS?
Can I use a gerenated cert on cloudflare with my AWS cert?
Should I get new certs from a 3rd party and use them in both Cloudflare and AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to acquire certs for CloudFlare since it breaks the protocol and inspects your communication and fronts your site. It isn't a pass through like you would see with a TCP load balancer.

The AWS certs on your ELB should be ok to leave in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure Cloudflare, it is best to use LetsEncrypt SSL Certificates. You would not need an ELB to implement SSL on the server which would help you in reducing costs.

You can visit https://certbot.eff.org/ and Select your server software and OS of your instance and it will show you the steps.

Also, Keep Full SSL in Cloudflare Settings under Crypto, "Full (Strict)" would probably not work

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)